# Use cases of bootstrapping maven

Tags: java, maven

I've seen some companies using maven bootstrap binary, instead of the one You get by the package manager.
What are the typical use cases of bootstrapping maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful when you want to use different Maven versions on different projects. Besides that it requires less setup on new environment, because the required version is encapsulated and under configuration control. Also, it can be the case of using a newer version that the one provided by the package manager.

[maven-wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) is a tool that simplifies this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

When you willing Docker as containers to build your app in clouds for example.